# Most efficient matrix multiplication in C using fork() and IPC

Tags: c, concurrency, ipc, fork, matrix-multiplication

I need to implement concurrent matrix multiplication in C using multiple processes. I understand that because each process has its own private address space, I will have to use some form of interprocess communication (IPC). I did some looking around and couldn't find many implementations that didn't use threads. I was wondering if anyone knew the most best way to go about this, either using shared memory, message passing, or pipes? I am not asking for a solution, but rather, if anyone knows, which of these methods will be more efficient with matrix multiplication. Or if there is a common standard way to do this with multiple processes?

Comment: Shared Memory has the advantage of avoiding additional copy operations, whereas pipes will need copies.

Comment: You could use MPI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface

Comment: Why are you avoiding threads?

Comment: I am not really avoiding them. I am writing two programs that do the same thing. One that forks child processes, the other uses pthreads, in order to see the difference in efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way of concurrently processing matrix multiplications would be shared memory. In this way, you don't have to serialize your matrix through a pipe/message and you can directly apply your multiplications on your shared memory space.

Answer (score 1):

**Shared memory** will be a good solution for this problem, I think. The processes can compute their solutions and share one memory to take the solutions together.

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
int shmget(key_t key, int size, int shmflg);
```

Is one of the C functions for shared memory (you'll need `shmat()` and maybe `shmdt()` and `shmctl()` too).

Also you have to care about synchronization so that the processes does not manipulate the computation from each other.

I would use **semaphores** for that: see [Semaphores in C](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/unix_guru/node394.html) and [Semaphore Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)

Comment: I would say that plain simple matrix multiplication doesn't suffer from race conditions

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems like I can do what I need to just by using fork() and join() without semaphores?